# How to get a specific ID from URL in php webdriver selenium?

Tags: url, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I was wondering how I would get a specific ID from an URL. ( If something like this is possible )

For example:

```
 // You are here: http://test.be/certificate/create
 // Saving new certificate 
 $search11 = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('certificate_save'));
 $search11->click();

 // You are here: http://test.be/certificate/11/basicinfo
 // Here I need to get the ID so I can go to the next page

 // You are here: http://test.be/certificate/11/holders
```

Basically I need the number after the /certificate/
Any suggestions? If something isn't clear feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Comment: Once you get the url ,you can apply string mainpulation on string url and then get the number after certificate/ sub string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the url from the Driver object and extract the id from that, something like this:

```
string url = Driver.Url;
string[] parts = url.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int id = int.Parse(parts[3]);
```

EDIT: Sorry just seen you are using php, my code was in c#, the same logic can be used for php as well

```
$url = $driver->getCurrentURL();
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$id = $parts[4];
```